# Can python program with wxPython be ported to android?

Tags: android, python, wxpython, sl4a

Can a program created using wxPython be ported to android using Scripting Environment [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and  [Python for Android](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/detail?name=PythonForAndroid_r4.apk) or any other better option? Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: I am afraid not, some discussion here http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Android-and-wxPython-td3324637.html

Comment: Tried using [kivy] (http://kivy.org/#home) that didn't help because of an OpenGL issue. If you could help me with that, we could figure out some workaround for building android apps using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wxPython does not currently support Android. You may be able to use the Kivy project which was already mentioned in the comments. There is a project for porting PyQt to Android that you can read about here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-for-android/22fJGoPy9kY/v--RY1UoCYkJ or you could go directly to their project page: http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/

I also saw a tutorial which helped generate the XML files behind some Android apps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405284/Writing-an-Android-GUI-using-Python-7-Activity

See also the following links:

- http://thp.io/2011/pyside-android/
- http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/fullscreenwrapper2